# Using the Catalan numbers

Tags: catalan-numbers

Here's a question we got for homework:

> A soccer match between team A and team B ends with a 9-9 tie. It is
>   know that at some point of the game team A had the lead and that later on it was
>   team B who had it. How many series's of 18 goals can represent the
>   course of the game?
>
> Hint: use the double-reflection technique.

So, this hint doesn't really help me as I don't understand what a double-reflection is.
Other than that: I thought about counting all possible series's which is the Catalan number C<sub>9</sub>, and then subtract all series's where B scored the first goal, but it's a little vague in my mind.

Any hints that would get me started would be great. Thanks!

Comment: The reflection principle is explained [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_ballot_theorem). (Regarding your third paragraph, note that the first goal may be scored by B.)

Comment: I understand the reflection principle, but what does double reflection means? Its probably a question for my TA but still...
Also - the way I understand the question A must score the first goal

Comment: I don't think there's an implication that team A must score the first goal. They had the lead *at some point*.

Comment: Ok, and if so - how do I start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: it's probably easier to count the ways that the condition can fail: that is, the number of series where B is winning/tied up to a certain turning point, and then A is winning/tied for the rest of the tournament.

Here's a canonical Catalan-type picture demonstrating this:

[image: Catalan-type picture]

The red-and-yellow marked point is the turning point here. Now, how can you use the reflection technique on this to get a Catalan graph where the black line is always above the diagonal? Can you use this to finish the problem?

Comment: If I reflect from the marked point and on, then I count all series where B is winning/tied (or A never lead). Is that all the ways for the condition to fail? What about a series where B never leads? Should I double the number I find to include both options?

Answer (score 3):

I wasn't able to solve the problem based only on Lopsy's hint, so here's a bit more.

First, it's all well and good to apply nifty reflection tricks, but they're a lot easier to find if you already know the result you're aiming for; so let's first mechanically derive the result using generating functions and then think about how to get it more elegantly.

The sequences that don't fulfill the requirement consist of a segment (possibly empty) in which $B$ is in the lead, followed by a segment (possibly empty) in which $A$ is in the lead.  Such segments where the lead doesn't change are counted by the Catalan numbers, so these invalid sequences are counted by a convolution of the Catalan numbers with themselves (with the sum running over the point where the lead changes). In terms of generating functions, that means that the generating function $G$ of the invalid sequences is the square of the generating function $C$ of the Catalan numbers. With

$$C(x)=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{2x}\;,$$

that yields

$$G(x)=C(x)^2=\frac1x\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}x-1\right)=\frac{C(x)-1}x\;.$$

Thus, $G$ is just $C$ with the constant term removed and shifted down by one, that is, $G_n=C_{n+1}$.

Knowing the result, it's a bit easier to see how to apply reflection. The problem in pursuing Lopsy's hint is that it's not obvious how to get a bijection – it's easy to reflect the part below the diagonal upward, but it's not clear what bijection that establishes. Knowing that we want to end up with the Catalan numbers one higher, we can use the extra slot to make the reflected sequence unique: By inserting an up-step before the reflected segment and a down-step after it, we get a bijection from the invalid sequences to the diagonal-avoiding sequences with two more steps, since the turning point is now uniquely marked as the last intersection with the diagonal in the new sequence.

Comment: The convolution of Catalan numbers which yields $G=C^2$ in your answer corresponds to @Lopsy's decomposition of each (in)admissible path into a path from (0,0) to some (x+1,x) which stays above the diagonal except at its endpoint, and a path from (x,x) to (9,10) which stays below the diagonal except at its endpoint.

Comment: @Didier: a) I don't understand why you're including an additional segment in the paths -- wouldn't it be more straightforward to say that the decomposition is into a path from (0,0) to (x,x) and one from (x,x) to (9,9)? b) I agree that this decomposition corresponds to the convolution; but I don't see how this gives a hint how to use reflection to set up a bijection.

Comment: Re (a), adding these elementary segments is not needed, but I mentioned the point (x+1,x) (and the corresponding one (9,10)) to make clear the reason why the decompoosition is bijective: one does not cut the global path at the first hitting of the diagonal but at its first crossing of the diagonal. Re (b), I guess the idea is to reflect the second portion so as to have two similar paths in succession. Here again I agree with you that this is not needed.

Comment: @Didier: Sorry, I might be being a bit dense, but I don't understand. I understand that the path is cut at the first crossing, not at the first hit, but once it's reflected, how does one decide which of the hits to turn into a crossing to get back to the original and make the mapping bijective? Or are you somehow using these additional segments in a similar way as I did in my answer to prevent any further hits in the reflected part? (I took Lopsy's hint to mean that one should simply reflect at the diagonal.)

Comment: Of course there is no bijection with the set of paths of length 18 entirely above the diagonal! (Otherwise one would have G=C.) Each such path p corresponds to as many admissible paths as the number n(p) of times it hits the diagonal. Surely true combinatorists know by heart that the generating function C^2 enumerates the collection of the paths p weighted by n(p)...

Comment: @Didier: I wouldn't dream of considering myself a true combinatorist :-) In fact a very large part of what I know about combinatorics I learned on this site over the last year. I'm afraid I still don't understand what you're getting at. Even assuming the routine knowledge of true combinatorists, that just tells us that a) the number of (in)admissible paths, b) the number of pairs of Dyck paths and c) the number of Dyck paths weighted by $n(p)$ are all the same -- but to know that this is the Catalan number one further up, we still need either the generating function computation or a bijection?

Comment: I believe Flajolet's school (and Flajolet himself) developed ways to automatize, to a certain extent, exactly that: the translation of decompositions of discrete structures and/or their weightings, in terms of relationships between the generating functions which enumerate them. Sorry to be so vague, but I do not have the time to expand on these at the moment. Slides of recent or semi-recent talks by Flajolet (or maybe Bousquet-Mélou's mini-course at ALEA 2011) surely explain this more congenially than I could.

Comment: @Didier: Nice coincidence -- I've been reading *Analytic Combinatorics* by Flajolet and Sedgewick over the holidays in order to give a better answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/93906/how-many-weakly-connected-digraphs-of-n-vertices-are-there-without-loops-and-who/93962#comment221206_93962). So I'm aware of their approach (though I wasn't two weeks ago), and that's probably why I came up with squaring the generating function -- but it seemed to me that the question asked for a bijective proof; that's what I was missing in the hint and wanted to provide.

Answer (score 2):

This follows closely Lopsy's suggestion and Joriki's answer. I copy here [my answer](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/sci.math/6-zv_rrmgiY/AlbtHTGRsIkJ) to [a problem from sci.math](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sci.math/6-zv_rrmgiY/overview).

---

**Question:** Suppose there are $n$ '$-1$' and $n$ '$+1$'. What is the recurrence relation for the permutations where all the subtotals beginning from the left is non-negative?

**Answer:** Let us call an arrangement of $n$ '$+1$'s and $n$ '$-1$'s a walk of type $n$. Let us also call a walk that has no negative partial sum a unilateral walk.

Let $w(n)$ be the number of unilateral walks of type $n$.  Let us classify these walks by the type of their smallest initial subwalk.  Those whose smallest initial subwalk is of type $k$ look like this:
$$
+1<\text{a unilateral walk of type }k{-}1>-1<\text{a unilateral walk of type }n{-}k>
$$
By considering all possible types of initial subwalk, we get the following recusive relation:
$$
w(n) = w(0)w(n-1) + w(1)w(n-2) + w(2)w(n-3) + \dots + w(n-1)w(0)\tag{1}
$$
with the initial condition that $w(0) = 1$.

Now that we have the recursive relation, let's try to find a closed form. The best way is to look at the generating function:
$$
f(x) = w(0) + w(1)x + w(2)x^2 + w(3)x^3 + \dots\tag{2}
$$
The recursive relation $(1)$ gives $f(x) = 1 + xf(x)^2$.  Solving this with the quadratic formula gives $f(x) = \frac{1 - \sqrt{1-4x}}{2x}$.  We can use the binomial theorem to get the power series for $\sqrt{1-4x}$, subtract that from $1$, and divide by $2x$.  This gives
$$
   f(x) = 1 + x + 2x^2 + 5x^3 + 14x^4 + \dots + \frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n} x^n + \dots\tag{3}
$$
And equating the coefficients of $(2)$ and $(3)$ we get $w(n) = \frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}$.

---

**Answer to the Misread Question**

At first, I misread the question as looking for the number of tied games where each side had the lead at some point. In case this answers some future query, I leave this solution, but note that it does not answer the question asked.

Since there are $\binom{2n}{n}$ walks of type $n$, subtracting the unilateral walks on both sides, there are
$$
\binom{2n}{n}-2C_n=\frac{n-1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}\tag{4}
$$
walks of type $n$ whose partial sums are both positive and negative.

---

**Answer to the Question Asked**

The question asks for the number of tie games where A has the lead at some point and B has the lead at a later point. The negation of this condition is a tie game where any lead B has is before any lead A has. So the number of games that we don't want to count is
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n\overbrace{\frac1{k+1}\binom{2k}{k}}^{\text{B leads}}\overbrace{\frac1{n-k+1}\binom{2n-2k}{n-k}}^{\text{A leads}}\tag5
$$
which is the convolution of the Catalan Numbers with themselves, whose generating function is the product of the generating functions for the Catalan Numbers. So the generating function for $(5)$ is $f(x)^2$, which by the relation above, $f(x)=1+xf(x)^2$, is
$$
\frac{f(x)-1}{x}\tag6
$$
That is, the number of tie games we don't want to count is $C_{n+1}$. Thus, the number of tie games we want to count is $\binom{2n}{n}-C_{n+1}$
$$
\binom{2n}{n}-C_{n+1}=\frac{n(n-1)}{(n+2)(n+1)}\binom{2n}{n}\tag7
$$

Comment: this isn't the same as the answer by @joriki if I'm reading everything correctly. His answer indicates we take the $n+1$th Catalan number and subtract that from $2n \choose n$. Your result seems different from that.

Comment: Let's consider $\binom{2n}{n}-\frac1{n+2}\binom{2n+2}{n+1}=\frac{n(n-1)}{(n+2)(n+1)}\binom{2n}{n}$. The first point at which this disagrees with my answer is $n=2$, where this gives $1$ and my answer gives $2$. Now let's count the number of $2$-$2$ ties that exist where each side has the lead at some point: $+--+$ and $-++-$; that is, $2$. Let's try $n=3$, where this gives $6$ and my answer gives $10$. Let's count: $$\begin{array}{c|c}+-+--+&-+-++-\\ +--++-&-++--+\\ -++-+-&+--+-+\\ ++---+&--+++-\\ -+++--&+---++\end{array}$$ That is, $10$.

Comment: The original question asks the number of sequences where A had the lead at some point and then B had it *at a later point*. For n=2 (a 2-2 tie), there is indeed only one way for this to happen. +,-,-,+ or (A,B,B,A)=>2-2. Sorry if I'm missing something.

Comment: Ah, I misread the question. However, it does not claim that A had the lead first, nor that B had it last, but simply that A had it at some point and B had it later. I will rethink.

Comment: Agree. But in the 2-2 draw case, the only way B can have the lead after A is if A has the lead first.

Comment: Yes, I know this is different than what I counted. As I said, I will rethink.

Comment: @RohitPandey: Now it matches.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what the above posters are talking about but I think this problem is straightforward. Basically A is in the lead for $r$ goals and then B takes the lead for the other $18-r$ goals.

So the answer is just:

$\sum_{r=1}^{17} C_r C_{18-r}$ where $C_n$ is the Catalan number $\frac{1}{n+1}{2n \choose n}$

Comment: This only works if you assume that after $B$ has taken the lead, $A$ never takes the lead anymore...

Comment: Yup you're right, I interpreted the question wrongly I guess haha

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it's actually much easier to apply the double reflection in the question hint than the generating function approach in the answers. If you reflect once (about y=1 where y is the goal deficit between A and B), you get the paths where A was in the lead at least once. This gives you ${2n \choose n-1}$, the term we subtract from the total paths to get the Catalan numbers. But, we want paths where A was in the lead and later, B was in the lead. So, we need to reflect one more time, this time about the line y=-1. When we do this, we get ${2n \choose n-2}$. Plug $n=9$ here and there's your answer. See the answer here: [Paths on a grid that don't go below $0$ or above $l$ before reaching their target.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3745584/paths-on-a-grid-that-dont-go-below-0-or-above-l-before-reaching-their-targe) for another demonstration of this "multiple reflection" trick in action.